# How to split a large string to two different arrays?

Tags: java

I'm working on an app where the user creates a large string containing a and b. Now I want to split the character `'a'` to one array or string and `'b'` to another array or string. And convert them to its original form when needed.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

String: `"abbabbaabbab"`
array1: `{'a','a','a','a','a'}`
array2: `{'b','b','b','b','b','b'}`

Comment: Where's your code?  What have you tried?

Comment: Why do you need arrays? Can't you just count the number of a and b in the string?

Comment: You can check here to understand how to deal with strings : https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple code and improve it to get your exact need (in this case get the "a" separately"):

```
public class Demo {
           public static void main(String []args) {
              String str = "aaabbbaaa";
              String a ="a";
              int counta = 0;

          System.out.println("String: "+str);
          for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
             if (str.charAt(i) == a.charAt(0)){
                 counta++;  }  }

              {for(int counter=0; counter < counta; counter++) 
                    System.out.print(a); } }  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason and purpose why you would want to do this isn't very clear, but nonetheless here is a space-efficient method to keep track of a,b in a string and recover the original string when the need arises -

1. Convert to byte code - Create a byte array and store 1 for a and 0 for b. Use this array to recover your string.
2. If you absolutely have to create 2 arrays with a and b, it wouldn't make much sense unless you store the positions of a and b as well, since you want to recover the original string at a later point. You can use HashMaps, but it would make more sense to store the indexes of a and b in two separate integer arrays.

Based on what exactly you want to achieve better solutions should be possible. Please update the question to provide more information about the same.